# Python: Read a file with raw records and build a sea level timeseries from it

Tags: python-3.x, replace, split, time-series, typeconverter

I have an ASCII file with monthly mean sea level records with multiple lines in the following form:

1969.0417;  7121; 0;000

1969.1250;-99999;00;000

1969.2083;  7121; 0;000

.......................

.......................

.......................

1970.1250;-99999;00;000

1970.2083;  7151; 0;000

1970.2917;  7131; 0;000

This is a 4 columns file holding time as years with 4 decimals, sea level as mm, and some values holding zeros for records. NaN value is -99999

I want my code to build a time series (a two columns list) that will hold:
i) the year values in the first column (as a float number)
and
ii) the sea level values in the second column (as a float number).
Once I got the sea level time series as an array of two columns with float numbers I think I can manage the rest of the processing and of the plots I need to do.

I am new to Python, so I tried different strategies.

If I had to do this for a single line I would do the following:

```
t=[]
sl=[]
line =('1969.0417;  7121; 0;000').replace(" ", "")
time = line.split(';')
t = float(time[0])
sl = float(time[1])
```

but I have to do it while reading the whole file, thus:

- First step, I open the file and read its lines:

  path=r"D:.....\4Python\1238.rlrdata"
  with open(path, "r") as f:
  for line in f:
  a = f.readlines()
- Second step, I tried to split the file using as delimiter ";"

  ```
        seg = a.split(';')
  ```

but I received the following message

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

- The next steps include replacing the " " with "", and converting the string to float.

Can you propose me any method?

Comment: So you have a list ```a=f.readlines()```.  This is a list of strings.  Instead of writing ```a.split()```, you'll want to iterate over the list and call the ```.split()``` method on each string in the list.

Comment: I guess you propose something like :

'    with open(path, "r") as f:
        a = f.readlines()
        for line in a:
            seg = a.split(';')
'

that still gives me :
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Almost, in your comment you are still trying to split the list, the ```.split()``` method does not apply to lists.  You would want something like ```for line in a: seg=line.split(";")``` then do what you need to with seg, whether that is store it or operate on it.

Comment: I would use pandas.read_table. Since you have a file you will need a with open as suggested above, then pass that file object to read_table with StringIO that will understand the ascii string.


https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html

Answer (score 0):

After all here is the solution:

```
# Open the file and read the data
with open(path) as f:
    data = f.readlines()

# Initialize an empty array to hold the data
array = np.zeros((len(data), 2))

# Loop over the lines in the file and fill in the array
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    # Split the line into two parts
    parts = line.strip().split(';')
    # Convert the parts to floats and add them to the array
    array[i, 0] = float(parts[0])
    array[i, 1] = float(parts[1])
```